# ParseQuery from field not save

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, field

ItemCount field not working

CategoryModel constructs is ItemCount = 0 not working

```
ParseObject parseObjectCategory = Categorylist.get(i);

                        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("List");
                        query.whereEqualTo("parent", parseObjectCategory);

                        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                            public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    itemCount = scoreList.size();
                                    Log.e("ItemCountGENERAL",""+itemCount);
                                } else {
                                    Log.e("Aldaa","---------------------------------------------------------------");
                                }
                                itemCount = scoreList.size();
                            }
                        });

                        Log.e("ItemCount",""+itemCount);

                        if(name.equals("Inbox")){
                            categoryMode1= new CategoryModel(itemData,name,R.drawable.ic_inbox, itemCount);
                        }else if(name.equals("Stared")){
                            categoryMode1= new CategoryModel(itemData,name,R.drawable.ic_stars, itemCount);
                        }else{
                            categoryMode1= new CategoryModel(itemData,name,R.drawable.ic_inbox, itemCount);
                        }

                        mainData.add(categoryMode1);
                        mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }`
```

My Image:

[image]

> Help Me 
>   [www.google.mn](http://www.google.mn)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add these code

```
                    if(name.equals("Inbox")){
                        categoryMode1= new CategoryModel(itemData,name,R.drawable.ic_inbox, itemCount);
                    }else if(name.equals("Stared")){
                        categoryMode1= new CategoryModel(itemData,name,R.drawable.ic_stars, itemCount);
                    }else{
                        categoryMode1= new CategoryModel(itemData,name,R.drawable.ic_inbox, itemCount);
                    }

                    mainData.add(categoryMode1);
                    mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
```

into the `FinalCallback`. 
You got 0 for `itemCount` because you are calling in an uninitialized field. `itemCount` got its value inside the `FinalCallback` which runs in a separate non UI thread which means the UI thread from where you are accessing it may run before the non UI thread. So you should move you logic which uses data that is retrieved from parse into `FinalCallback`